# How do I keep items that are being appended to a python list in order - order of input

Tags: python, list

I want to ask the user for an undetermined amount of numbers. I will convert those numbers to integers and store them in a list for calculations later.

I will then ask the user for more undetermined amount of numbers and do the same. Then I want to multiply the numbers in order for example:

(GymBot Project)

```
input("Enter total reps") 
#user enters: 10 12 12 12 

input("Enter weight used") 
#user enters: 120 110 125 125
```

These would be stored in:

```
user_reps = [] 
user_weight = []
```

but they are entered in at random indexes. What I want is:

```
user_reps = [10 12 12 12]
user_weight = [120 110 125 125]
```

not random indexes or based on value etc. Just keep it exactly how it was entered.

My goal is to multiply the weight * reps and obtain a value for output the user later.

This is what I'm working on....https://github.com/iko172302/python3_gym_bot.git

I'm sure I confused everyone lol

Comment: It’s not clear why they are stored at random indexes.

Comment: So, what exactly is the question? What did you try that didn't work? Please include your code.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The program was done - then I realized I was getting the wrong calculation at the end. In a nut shell I take user input sets, reps, weights and output total sets, total reps and total weight lifted. For total weight lifted the formula would be total reps * total weight for a given set. The whole code is here: https://github.com/iko172302/python3_gym_bot.git

Comment: I'll slice out the part I'm talking about one sec.

Comment: How are you entering the inputs into the list? Lists in python are ordered data structures. If you are using `user_reps.append(10)` and `user_weight.append(120)` the positioning should remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

#### Code

```
from operator import mul

inp1 = input('Enter total reps')
user_reps = list(map(int, inp1.split()))

inp2 = input('Enter weight used')
user_weights = list(map(int, inp2.split()))

print('User reps', user_reps)
print('User weights', user_weights)

res = list(map(mul, user_reps, user_weights))

print('Result', res)
```

#### Output

```
User reps [2, 3, 4, 5]
User weights [7, 6, 5, 33]
Result [14, 18, 20, 165]
```

You need to add some checks for ensuring both sizes are equal.

Comment: @MatthewChamplin let me know if this fits to your needs or if I am missing something

Comment: When I enter `[1, 2, 3]` I get `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'` and when I enter `3, 3, 3` I get `'tuple' object has no attribute 'split`' Is this only for Python 3?

Comment: @JosuéCortina thank you! I know my question was confusing but you nailed it! I plugged your answer into the bug in my code and all calculated properly. I will be more clear next time I ask! Sorry the first question here- usually just find my answers without asking.

Comment: @MatthewChamplin you are welcome, please, mark my answer as **accepted** (green checkmark) and upvote it. Thnx in advance!